# cant fetch recent tweets of a user

Tags: api, twitter, tweets

when i print $tweets it gives me array with error like

> [body] => {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}

```
private function fetch_tweets($tweet_count,$username){
    $tweets = wp_remote_get("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$username.json");

    print_r($tweets);

    if(isset($tweet->error) ) return false;

    foreach($tweets as $tweet){
        if($tweet_count-- === 0) break;
        echo $tweet->text;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to GET an incorrect URL, rather than sending the appropriate parameters to the correct API endpoint.  Might I suggest referring to the [Twitter API documentation for `GET statuses/user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Comment: Couldn't that be the mispell in your code? usern_timeline (the n in user).

Comment: sorry, my bad..it was typo..

Answer (score 1):

As ardavey mentioned, you need to read the [API Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline):

> Example Request
>
> `GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2`

So, for your PHP:

```
$tweets = wp_remote_get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=$username");
```

Also, not that you will need to authenticate your request:

> Please note that the API requires that the request be authenticated (check Authentication & Authorization documentation...

See [Auth Overview](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview) to get started.